# Android multi modules annotation processing

Tags: java, android, annotation-processing

In a multi modules Android project annotation processing is still executed as a first task before any compilation is done and then a complete compilation is triggered. Of course this is done per module before getting into the `app` module.

Imagine a case where some child modules depend on others, the compilation will fail as the dependant cannot **yet** find definition for generated classes in the module that it depends on simply because they were not generated yet.

I am wondering if there's a way either using `gradle` or anything else to force execute all child modules annotation processing first and then compile the whole project in an automatic fashion. This means if I have 3 modules let's name them `app`, `services` and `executors` where `services` depends on `executors`.

What I am seeking is that the build tree would go in this order:

1. annotation processing is executed for all modules without compilation
2. a full project compilation is then invoked

I found so far some promising lead using the `java compiler's` option `-proc:{none;only}` where the value `only` should invoke the annotation processing without any further compilation. I have tried passing this `option` to my compiler but **still** the compilation goes sequentially child module per child module.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am willing to put a bounty on this one!

Comment: The Annotation processor will generate some source files to be used later by the app. I have asked also somewhere else and I've got some promising leads. It turns out that my problem was with `configuration` not `execution`. I will post a solution once I'm done implementing it. Mean while if you have a solution please go ahead and post it. Thanks

Comment: can you clarify what gradle version you are using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a deep investigation on this subjects, long hours of reading and many tee and coffee cups, I have across the fact that my project setup was not quite correct also I have figured out that Kotlin android plugin has its own sad and shady fact which I hope I can clarify in this very answer so grab a cup of tee/coffee and enjoy reading.

1. Is there a way to trigger a kotlin compilation twice?
   Short answer for that is **NO!**, this is simply due to the fact that `gradle` it self has an **Acyclic** dependency graph which means there should be no way to have a **circular** dependency hence a task will only run once per `gradle` invocation.
2. How to can we solve this limitation?
   There are two options, either we add a new `Source set` (for android that will be through adding a new `buildType`) or simply break the wonders of the chicken/egg dilemma and use artifacts.

I have experimented a lot with every possible solution but still, something was smelling fishy. First thing first, [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/force-rerun-a-task-by-another-task/36295) is a thread where I asked `gradle` users about my problem. Even though, It didn't solve my problem, it still shed some light on the roots of the issue itself,**The chicken/egg dilemma**.

Trying to clarify further my problem, I went ahead with my investigations and asked `kotlin` developers about how to do this using kotlin gradle plugin. Please find the answers [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-35738#focus=streamItem-27-4176485.0-0)

Short story: **There is no way to extend the kotlinCompile gradle task directly** simply cuz there is a "code around" that initiate the compilation. I mean sure but why it was very poorly designed this way? Why such a beautiful language as `kotlin` had to rush the production of that specific **supposedly powerful** plugin, and mostly why its sources was never updated/reviewed ever since?

The way around this is to use their handle [KotlinCompilation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html#configuring-compilations) entry point. I personally don't like this solution as it limits the level of flexibility and also still abstract the compilation task even further.

Another promising way using gradle was `artifacts` where a module builds it self and produces an artifact (usually a jar in our case) which will be consumed by other projects. This sounds cool right? Well unfortunately there is no way to add this library to the classpath of `consumers` and the compilation will simply fail.

These were my findings, please feel free to update my knowledge or correct me if I am mistakingly understanding something.

Happy coding!